# Spring property initialization of class

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Good Morning,
I'm required to make a static inner class to initialize the property of a bean. The problem is
this bean is a generic class and is used in other areas where this property is not required to
be initialized. The way I'm doing it is

In application-context.xml

```
<bean id="innerBean" class="innerBeanClass$inner" />
<bean id="myClass" class="Foo">
    <property name="dummy" ref="innerBean" />
</bean>
<bean id="yourClass" class="Foo" />
<!-- no property initialization for this version of foo. --!>
```

In Foo.java

```
public class Foo {
    private Function<A, B> dummy = null; 
   /* innerBeanClass$inner inherits Function<A,B>*/
....
}
```

Is it right? Is there sth that I may be missing?

Comment: Semms correct to me. Do you have a stacktrace or sth?

Comment: Nothing failed yet. Never used spring before, have to run it, wanted more of a validation before testing

Comment: Specifically the initialization to null part in class Foo

Comment: Why do people do that? Just run it. It's not like it will break anything if it doesn't run.

Comment: Asking feedback from the community. trying to see if there are better ways to accomplish the same thing. Mostly, it boils down to the fact, at least in my case, that I'm a C++ programmer and am learning the ropes of java/spring. Anyways gng ahead and answering my own question

Answer (score 0):

Should have defined a setter for dummy as in

```
public void setDummy(Function<A,B> dummy) {
    this.dummy = dummy;
}
```

This is what the stack trace indicated and another application specific bug. It works after both the issues were resolved.